# Calculation of Precision,Recall and F-Score with confusionMatrix

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, confusion-matrix

We have developed an algorithm that detects number of repetions per resistance exercise machine out of accelerometer data. People performed always 10 repetitions 2x per machine.

> n people x 10 repetitions x 2 sets = total amount of repetitions performed .

Now, I wanted to calculate the `precision`, `recall` and `f-score` with `confusionMatrix` from the `caret` package.

I made an `xlsx` file with two rows representing real (upper row) and algorithmically predicted number of repetitions (lower row) as depicted in the picture:

[image]

I coded the following:

```
reps_prec_phone1<- read.xlsx("Reps_for_Precision_Recall_FSCORE.xlsx", sheet =  "2Vec_Phone1", startRow = 0, colNames = FALSE) 
reps_prec_pred_phone1<-as.factor(reps_prec_phone1[1,])
reps_prec_real_Phone1<-as.factor(reps_prec_phone1[2,])

result_phone1 <- confusionMatrix(reps_prec_pred_phone1, reps_prec_real_Phone1, mode="prec_recall")
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the `confusionMatrix`, 385 sets (1 set consists of 10 repetitions) instead of `3850` repetitions were counted. Now I am wondering, methodologically how can I get `confusionMatrix` to calculate the number of repetitions instead of the number of sets.

In my case the error rate is `1-Accuracy = 2.5%`. As 1 set consists of 10 repetitions. As set vs repetition is a factor of 10, I could simply divide the error rate by 10 and recalulate the accuracy `1-0.0025 = 0.9975`. However,

- does anyone know how to solve this issue with `confusionMatrix`?

Thank you in advance for your brain power & experience!

Comment: What is 11 and 10 in the data? Does your model use 0 for 10 and 1 for 11 ? What is the amount of the test set? I just wonder if you choose 0.1 ratio for assigning the Test data or not. By the way, your data seemed very imbalanced to me, the accuracy score may be misleading.

Comment: 10 = 10 real (upper row) repetitions, 11 = 11 predicted (lower row) repetitions

Comment: I still don't understand. Is that a classification model or a regression model? If you talk about the accuracy score, it must be a classification model. And there must exist some categorical variables to run it. What I understand from your question is, there are 2 types of categories which are "10" and "11" in the entire data. And you predicted it via a model and now trying to find the accuracy etc. I asked you the amount of the TEST data set to point that the result may stem from the amount of the TEST data since it is a sample from the real data set.

Answer (score 0):

There's a theoretical mistake.

A confusion matrix is made to compare observations given with *predicted* values, `R` convert your data as factor, then your values {10,11} are interpreted as the levels of that factor not as numeric values, then `R` count the ties. In short put, **you have a wrong idea about what a confusion matrix is**.

Also, any model will perform biased predictions because you have extremely unbalanced data, in short put, **there's nothing to predict**.

Then, you don't have a programming problem it's more a theoretical one. Visit Stack Exchange to clear your ideas.

[Visit me!](https://stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for enlighting me :)